# In CasperJS can I turn off an event handler => send click event without a resize event

Tags: javascript, jquery, casperjs

I'm testing a page that has an event handler that reloads the page on resize.
It is interfering with testing, and I would like to turn it off.

On the page, the handler is:

```
        $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
            if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
            window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
                this.location.reload(false); /* false to get page from cache */
            }, 100);
        });
```

So in CasperJS, I tried doing this:

```
        this.evaluate(function() {
            $(window).unbind('resize');
        });
```

No success though. I'd rather turn it off from CasperJS than make changes to the page.

[UPDATE] Although I have been unable to unbind the resize event handler, I managed to send a click from CasperJS/PhantomJS without triggering a resize event. In case this is helpful to you, here is the code for that:

```
// This is a workaround alternative to this.click(link)
// It does not trigger a resize event. (1 test)
function myclick( test, casper, link ) {
    test.assertExists(link);
    test.comment('myclick: send click event to ' + link);
    casper.evaluate(function(link) {
        var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evt.initEvent('click', true, false);
        document.querySelector(link).dispatchEvent(evt); 
    }, link);
}
```

You could call it like this:

```
        myclick( test, casper, 'a#logout' );
```

So now I don't have to disable the resize event handler.

Comment: Try inserting `$(window).bind('resize', (e) => { e.preventDefault(); return false; })` after the page's code

Comment: Wouldn't that be changing the behaviour when the page is viewed in a browser? I only want to temporarily disable it during a test.

Comment: http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate

Comment: Thank you. I am familiar with that page. I am using it to try and unbind the event handler.

Comment: I can think of a couple of ways to achieve that, but it would be *far* easier to just adjust the page for testing. Since you haven't given a proper description of *how* it interferes with the test, I suspect that this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: I am just keen to know if you can use evaluate() to turn off an event handler. It does not seem to work for me so far. Has anyone done this before? And since CasperJS calls PhantomJS evaluate(), perhaps the answer is there somewhere.

Comment: This is related, someone else had the same trouble.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/eEmZ4QSylpU